# How can I run a program hundreds of times using Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program which I need to call more than 100 times with different values.

I want to do it simultaneously that is not wait for one call to complete and then to start again.

How can I achieve it ?

Is multithreading the solution to it.

I am using python for it.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a DoS attack, in order to find out what would happen?

Comment: no I just a have a list of jobs which I need to run efficiently and test it whether it can withhold the DoS attack

Comment: @Jaimin Shah: Couldn't you do load / stress test. Stress test should produce same effect as DoS attack. All you want is to overwhelm your server with request and see how it behaves.

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of what you've got so far.

Comment: Is the program you're running also in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. Here is an example that runs the `sleep` command a hundred times, with a sleep value between 0 and 10 seconds. It runs them all in parallel and then exits when they all finish.

```
import subprocess
import time

bin_path = 'sleep'
invocation_args = [[str(x*0.1)] for x in range(0,100)]

subprocs = []
for args in invocation_args:
    subprocs.append(subprocess.Popen([bin_path] + args))

while len(subprocs) > 0:
    subprocs = [p for p in subprocs if p.poll() is None]
    time.sleep(0.05)

print 'Finished running all subprocs'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [pyCUDA](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda). It uses multithreading and runs on NVIDIA's GPU's.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, this may not actually be the best way to achieve your goal, depending on exactly what your goal is.

However, if you decide you want to do it this way, look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module for Python.  You will need to directly use Popen rather than the convenience functions like call since the convenience functions would wait for the called process to end.

Alternatively, you could use [os.spawn](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.spawnl) with a P_NOWAIT option, but Popen is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for some kind of stress/load testing maybe existing open-source solutions would be more appropriate, e.g. jMeter (java) or  TheGrinder (Java with scripts in Jython).